# Java reading from binary file

Tags: java, windows, ubuntu, io, binary

I have some calculated data (floats and integers), which is written to a 12mb file like this

```
DataOutputStream os3;
os3 = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(Cache.class.getResource("/3w.dat").getPath()));
...... (some loops)
     os3.writeFloat(f);
     os3.writeInt(r);
os3.close();
```

And after that I read it this way

```
DataInputStream is3;
is3 = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(Cache.class.getResource("/3w.dat").getPath()));
...... (same loops)
     is3.readFloat();
     is3.readInt();
is3.close();
```

So, I wrote file only once on Windows 7. After that I only read it while app starts. File reading works fine on Windows 7, but when I try do to it on Ubuntu, I get EOF exception (code and file are the same).

I suspect problem may be caused by some NaN values written to the file.

BTW. While debugging I figured out that on ubuntu reading process runs about 15% of loop and throws an exception. All values it reads are "0.0", but file doesnt contain zeros.

Comment: When you *try* it on Ubuntu, does this entail writing and reading or just reading (that is, you read the file generated by the application running on Windows)?

Comment: I just read it on Ubuntu

Comment: What would happen if you where to write and read on Ubuntu?

Comment: you can try replace the \n with \r\n as the end of line character is different from windows to linux

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be the different of line break between Linux and Windows. As mentioned by Clark, just replace the \n with \r\n and the end of line character could resolve this. You can use Notpad++ to simplify this work. Just click on Menu :

> Edit -> EOL conversion -> Convert to UNIX format

It might be also a problem of encoding. If you'are using Windows, the default encoding is Windows-1252 or so called CP-1252, which is specially microsoft thing and cannot be recognized on Linux. Just change it into an encoding like UTF-8 which can be recognized by all OS. Using Notpad++:

> Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8

Comment: Its a binary file. There is no \n or \r\n

Comment: then write your file with UTF-8